# 64GB USB flash drive partitioned for Kali Linux persistent USB boot. Primary OK, logical unkown, will not format

Tags: linux, usb-flash-drive, kali-linux, boot-partition

I recently set up Kali Linux on a Toshiba 16gb USB flash drive with persistence. I can boot the drive up and it will save all setting etc. So I decided to get a 64GB flash drive to do the same.

The issue I have is that the drive needs to be partitioned, so after the ISO image is written to it from Universal USB installer, I opened Minitool partition wizard and resized the primary partitions to 32GB. The unallocatted 32GB needs to be Primary, Ext4 partition labelled persistence, but when I attempt to create this is shows the file system as unknown. I opened the drive in Gparted also and although it shows that it is creating it to Ext4, it then goes back to Unknown.

I have tried to also recreate in NTFS and get the same result. It is an unbranded USB but i have checked and the drive in GetDriveInfo and get the following result:

```
Volume: D:
Controller: Alcor 0xF101
Possible Memory Chip(s):
Intel 29F64G08ACME3
Intel 29F64G08AAME1
Intel 29F64G08ACMF3
Intel 29F64G08LCME1
Intel 29F64G08ACME2
Memory Type: MLC
Flash ID: 8988244B A9
Flash CE: 1
Chip F/W: FA00
Group: 98
VID: 0000
PID: 7777
Manufacturer: Generic
Product: Mass Storage
Query Vendor ID: Generic
Query Product ID: Flash Disk
Query Product Revision: 8.07
Physical Disk Capacity: 67108864000 Bytes
Windows Disk Capacity: 33529626624 Bytes
Internal Tags: AYWR-SY24
File System: FAT32
Relative Offset: 16384 KB
USB Version: 2.00
Declared Power: 200 mA
ContMeas ID: 1575-09-00
```

If anyone can let me know what is going and how it can be resolved it would be much appreciatted.

Comment: Is getdriveinfo a default tool on Kali?

Comment: As far as i know its a default app on linux

Comment: Well, I can't find anything about it, it's not on [packages.ubuntu.com](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=get%20info&searchon=all&suite=all&section=all). All I can find is this question and stuff relating to C# methods. On kali.org all I find is `diskutil`, and standard tools ...

Comment: Apologies, i used this tool in Windows 7. It can be downloaded. I do t have a link but i used it to see what chipset some pen drives had as there was a specific type i wanted for another project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess it would be easier to get disk image for each mount point/partition you have with the help of Clonezilla. Afterward, you can create a new partition table for 64GB drive and restore images of a 16GB drive to the 64GB one.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. After much trying and failing i have decided the best solution is to by another Toshiba drive. Thats what I get for buying a cheap drive of Ebay :)