# The term "Internal Tags" in the properties of USB Flash Drives

Tags: usb-flash-drive

Related to the information given [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1156616/64gb-usb-flash-drive-partitioned-for-kali-linux-persistent-usb-boot-primary-ok)

```
Volume: D:
Controller: Alcor 0xF101
Possible Memory Chip(s):
Intel 29F64G08ACME3
Intel 29F64G08AAME1
Intel 29F64G08ACMF3
Intel 29F64G08LCME1
Intel 29F64G08ACME2
Memory Type: MLC
Flash ID: 8988244B A9
Flash CE: 1
Chip F/W: FA00
Group: 98
VID: 0000
PID: 7777
Manufacturer: Generic
Product: Mass Storage
Query Vendor ID: Generic
Query Product ID: Flash Disk
Query Product Revision: 8.07
Physical Disk Capacity: 67108864000 Bytes
Windows Disk Capacity: 33529626624 Bytes
Internal Tags: AYWR-SY24
File System: FAT32
Relative Offset: 16384 KB
USB Version: 2.00
Declared Power: 200 mA
ContMeas ID: 1575-09-00
```

What does the term "Internal Tags: AYWR-SY24" means or implies for a USB Flash Drive in the OP question in the link?

Is there any official / standard document that points to the definition of this?

Note: this is not a duplicate question. It explicitly asking a different term.

Comment: What tool gave you this information? A quick search lead to ["_Flash Drive Information Extractor_"](https://www.antspec.com/usbflashinfo/index.php), I suspect that "_Internal Tags_" comes under their "_some other parameters useful for specialists_" bullet (translated).

Comment: @Attie since their definition may not be related to each other (e.g. what's the relation between the definition of "max. power" with "internal tags"?) I divided the questions to make things easier for you to answer... assuming you have an answer that is.

Comment: @Attie yes you are correct. I used the software  "Flash Drive Information Extractor". Just emailed the creator of that software asking about it but no reply.